# What is the limit of $\cos{(\pi x)}$ as $x$ approaches $-3$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find $\lim_{x \to -3} \cos{\pi x}$. Enter the exact value for the limit, using $\exp{(x)}$ to denote $e^x$ and Pi to denote $\pi$ where needed.

Just wanting to confirm the answer is 1?

Comment: If you just want to confirm such a simple fact, i.e [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+cos(pi*x)+for+x+to+-3) is always there for you :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was unsure on how to express the limit in words. Now I know :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the function $f(x)=\cos(\pi x)$ is a continuous function on the entire real line. This means that the limit of this function at any given point is going to be equal to its functional value at that point:

$$
\lim_{x \to -3} \cos{(\pi x)}=\cos{(-3\pi)}=-1.
$$

So, the answer of $1$ that you got is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \to -3} \cos{\pi x}= \cos(-3 \pi)= \cos(-2 \pi- \pi)= \cos(- \pi)=-1.$